# how to remove the master password for the alpine pine e-mail client?

Tags: command-line, ssh, password, encryption, email-client

referencing:

https://comp.mail.pine.narkive.com/UcMK4NZG/suppress-master-password-prompt

how is the master password prompt suppressed?  If memory serves this is indeed possible.  As I recall, the file is "sort of" decrypted and then re-created so that it's no longer encrypted...but I wasn't able to find the instructions.

```
For Copyright information press "?"
Enter password of key <MasterPassword> to unlock password file:                                                                     
                                                                                                                                    
^C Cancel             Ret Accept
```

The specific file is:

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ ls -alh .pine-passfile 
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 855 Jul  2 09:55 .pine-passfile
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

there's a procedure to remove the password to this file, so that the alpine client can still use the passwords in the file but won't prompt the user for the master password to the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to work:

```
$ pwd
/home/nicholas/.alpine-smime/.pwd

$ ll
total 20
drwx------ 2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 30 15:08 ./
drwx------ 6 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 30 15:06 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 1054 Apr 30 15:06 MasterPassword.crt
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 1679 Apr 30 15:08 MasterPassword.key
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 1854 Apr 30 15:06 MasterPassword.key.orig

$ mv MasterPassword.key MasterPassword.key.orig
$ openssl rsa -in MasterPassword.key.orig -out MasterPassword.key
writing RSA key

$ ll
total 20
drwx------ 2 nicholas nicholas 4096 Jul  2 22:33 ./
drwx------ 6 nicholas nicholas 4096 Apr 30 15:06 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nicholas nicholas 1054 Apr 30 15:06 MasterPassword.crt
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 1679 Jul  2 22:33 MasterPassword.key
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 1679 Apr 30 15:08 MasterPassword.key.orig
```

source:

https://www.ccdw.org/node/14

https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2023

---

see also:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331927/101935

which explains, amongst other things:

```
touch .yourpassfile
alpine -passfile .yourpassfile
```

as a precursor the above solution.